# Vertically align Unordered List with images and text that is displayed below the image?

Tags: css, image, html-lists, vertical-alignment

Ok, so I need some help in vertically aligning an unordered list with images and text all inside the same element. The image should align vertically with the text directly below it.

*Here is my code:*

**html:**

```
<div id="sidetrans">
<ul>
<li><a data-ftrans="slide" href="slide2.html">iPhone 1&2<img alt="next"      src="images/iphone1.png" height="115" width="87" /></a></li>
<li><a data-ftrans="slide" href="">iPhone 3G<img alt="next" src="images/iphone1.png" height="115" width="87" /></a></li>
<li><a data-ftrans="slide" href="">iPhone 3GS<img alt="next" src="images/iphone1.png" height="115" width="87" /></a></li>
<li><a data-ftrans="slide" href="">iPhone 4<img alt="next" src="images/iphone1.png" height="115" width="87" /></a></li>
<li><a data-ftrans="slide" href="">iPhone4S<img alt="next" src="images/iphone1.png" height="115" width="87" /></a></li>
<li><a data-ftrans="slide" href="">iPhone5<img alt="next" src="images/iphone1.png" height="115" width="87" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#sidetrans {
padding-top:15px;
text-align:left;}

#sidetrans a{
padding:0; }

#sidetrans a img{
 vertical-align: text-bottom;   }

#sidetrans ul li{
display:inline;
list-style: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understand this right. You want to all links in vertical and text below image. So if you do some change in html that will be good. Put text after image, and then put display: block; for image.

```
img {
display: block;
}
```

[check this pen](http://codepen.io/crazyrohila/pen/tHyDm)

Comment: Pretty sure the OP still wants the list items to appear inline:  http://jsfiddle.net/5kUfg/.

Comment: updated the pen, if he wants list to appear inline. but If don't then remove float:left; from css.

Comment: Can you please fix the broken link?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line. You does not need this lines .

```
#sidetrans ul li{
display:inline;
list-style: none;}
```

Please check this http://jsbin.com/oqeteh/5/edit